# Selenium chrome headless cannot execute onclick event on Linux server

Tags: python, linux, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am having trouble porting over a Python Selenium headless google chrome script from Windows to a Linux server that navigates to a website and downloads a file. The script runs **without errors** on **windows** and on a **linux** server, however the script on the **linux** server never downloads a file.

I am not sure what may be the issue. I thought it may be a permission issue, but I ran a small script using the wget package and it downloaded the file in to the specified folder.

What do you think may be preventing the same script from downloading a file on the linux server? The server has the latest chrome and chromedriver installed (Version 81) and my program correctly points to them.

**This script works and downloads the icon**

```
import wget
url = "https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo@2x.png"
wget.download(url, '/external/gen_dir')
```

**This script runs and shuts the driver but never downloads anything(Works in Windows on my personal computer when pointed to the correct folders on my local machine). There are no script breaking errors** Has same download location as above script so I do not think it is a permissions issue. Both scripts were executed from the same folder.

```
from selenium import webdriver
print('packages imported')
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
print('options imported')

#specifying headless and download options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'team/mm/chromedriver', options=options)


#'/external/gen_dir'  directory for sample data

params = {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': r'/external/gen_dir'}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', params)
print('download paramaters executed')

driver.get("https://www.thinkbroadband.com/download")

# initialize an object to the location on the html page and click on it to download
search_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#main-col > div > div > div:nth-child(8) > p:nth-child(1) > a > img')
search_input.click()

driver.quit()
print('driver closed')
```

Comment: Could you please use the javascript executor to perform a click on that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's because driver.quit() ran before download started, so

```
search_input.click()
time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hi Philippe. That worked. I wanted to ask why would you think that on my Windows machine, I did not need to put the sleep timer but it was essential to be added to the script on the Linux server?

Comment: Your original script didn't work for me on Windows either, so it's hard for me to find out. Can you double check it worked for you on Windows ?

Comment: HI Philippe, I can explain why it worked on my computer. I wrote it in Jupyter notebook and the driver.quit() line was in a separate cell so as i was running the different Jupyter cells I was inadvertently delaying execution. But yes if I put all the code in one cell, nothing is downloaded in windows as well.

Comment: That explains. You still need to find a more robust way than `time.sleep(5)` for bigger files for example.

Comment: I know. I need to write a check  that delays action until file number in the download folder increments by one (and maybe check that the file has downloaded fully). Thank you for your help though